# WebView how to get local res\drawable-hdpi image path

Tags: android

I have a WebView and I want to add a backgroung Image

```
String htmlPage = "<HTML><BODY background=\"bgrnd.png\" TEXT=\"black\">";
```

the problem is how to get the image path "bgrnd.png" which is saved in res"\drawable-hdpi" folder.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your images into assets folder and you can use like this way into your image tag

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/images/yourimage.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml use

```
android:background="@+drawable/bgrnd.png"
```

Set 
`mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);` below your string